# how to update a column with the default value set during creation in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to update a column to the default value given during creation.
I need to do this inside a function, and was wondering if there was a way to do this in such a way that i don't have to change my code in case the default value changes later.

I am using Postgres v11

Comment: What do you mean with "during creation"? Do you mean when you do `alter table ... add ...`?

Comment: During "creation" I assume you mean when the table was created, ed `create table t (name text not null with default WHAT_IS_THIS)`? See dupe.

Comment: yes like @Bohemian said i mean the default value that was given to a column during creation.

Comment: on a separate note @a_horse_with_no_name, big fan. : )